# Living in the Netherlands, working in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, eu, netherlands, freelance

I am a 21 year old British female who, upon graduation of my masters in September, will be moving to the Netherlands to live with my partner.

I am hoping to boost my career in freelance writing upon moving, and currently work for a couple of people over here in the UK. I have received a substantial number of offers to work on a full-time formal basis when I graduate, and I'm hoping to take them up on the offer despite the fact that I will be living abroad, as all work can be completed remotely.

My only issue is that of the Dutch tax system. How (if it's even possible, or worth it) would I go about living in the Netherlands, yet working for UK clients and earning pounds sterling by doing so? Also, what is the protocol for working freelance in the Netherlands? Could anyone help me with this? Any information or advice whatsoever would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep working on freelance basis you could start your own business. Starting a business in the Netherlands is, in my experience as a native, fairly easy and inexpensive (around €65 in total). You can find more information at http://www.kvk.nl/english/starting-a-business/

*The Kamer van Koophandel (KvK / Chamber of Commerce) is the institution where you register your business in The Netherlands.

Welcome to The Netherlands and Good luck!

Comment: Fully agree that this is probably the smartest way to do things. @lorilai18 this does mean your income will need to be taxed in the Netherlands (and generally it is advisable to have a Dutch bank account for your company). Generally you'd also bill them in Euro's and there are some VAT rules (since it's within EU you can reverse charge this) plus extra filings because of this. We've gone through all this with our business so if you'd like to chat more about details just let me know. I can highly advise you getting a bookkeeper for ~100€ a month to make sure it's all done correctly.